# How to switch rows into columns using css

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to change rows into columns using css. This is what my actually code looks like:

```
<style>
    .flex-container {
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .flex-item {
        width: 25%;

    }

</style>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">3</div>
    <div class="flex-item">4</div>
    <div class="flex-item">5</div>
    <div class="flex-item">6</div>
    <div class="flex-item">7</div>
    <div class="flex-item">8</div>
    <div class="flex-item">9</div>
    <div class="flex-item">10</div>
    <div class="flex-item">11</div>
    <div class="flex-item">12</div>
    <div class="flex-item">13</div>
    <div class="flex-item">14</div>
    <div class="flex-item">15</div>
    <div class="flex-item">16</div>
    <div class="flex-item">17</div>
    <div class="flex-item">18</div>
    <div class="flex-item">19</div>
</div>
```

In the browser i have this: first step

[image]

I need to have that: final step

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use Flex-direction to change the direction of flex from row to column . By default the direction of flex is ROW . by using flex-direction:col we can switch from row to column.

```
flex-direction:column;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex-direction` to switch a flex layout from row to col. Define the direction in the wrapper component

```css
flex-direction: column;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `flex-directon` to `column` and give some height to the parent element

```css
.flex-container {
        max-width: 500px;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
         height: 100px;
    }

    .flex-item {
        width: 25%;
       
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">3</div>
    <div class="flex-item">4</div>
    <div class="flex-item">5</div>
    <div class="flex-item">6</div>
    <div class="flex-item">7</div>
    <div class="flex-item">8</div>
    <div class="flex-item">9</div>
    <div class="flex-item">10</div>
    <div class="flex-item">11</div>
    <div class="flex-item">12</div>
    <div class="flex-item">13</div>
    <div class="flex-item">14</div>
    <div class="flex-item">15</div>
    <div class="flex-item">16</div>
    <div class="flex-item">17</div>
    <div class="flex-item">18</div>
    <div class="flex-item">19</div>
</div>
```

Here's the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mastering_Wrapping_of_Flex_Items)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but this solution works only when i know height of the flex-container. In my scenario i dont know the height because it is depends on amount of flex-item

Comment: Welcome. In that case, you can give `max-height` instead of `height`. It works the same way

Answer (score 0):

You can use a short-hand called `flex-flow`

```
flex-flow: column wrap;
```

Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow) docs for more info.